# How to get scrolled value on horizontally-vertical scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a web page that scrolls horizontally when you scroll vertical. And I want the scrolled value on scrolling. [Here is what I have done](https://redstapler.co/pure-css-horizontal-scrolling-website-tutorial/)

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#log {
    position: fixed;
    width: 500px;
    height: 25px;
    border: solid black 1px;
    z-index: 999;
}

img{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 50%;
    left: 90vw;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
}

.outer-wrapper {
    height: 100vw;
    width: 100vh;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    scrollbar-width: none;  /*---Firefox property---*/
    -ms-overflow-style: none; /*---i.e. family---*/
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;  /*---Chrome and Safari*/
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 400vw;
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
}


.slide {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
.slide1 {
    background-color: teal;
}
.slide2 {
    background-color: tomato;
}
.slide3 {
    background-color: slateblue;
}
.slide4 {
    background-color: palevioletred;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Horizonral scroll</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img draggable="false" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/arrow_right_alt1-512.png" alt="arrow_right" width="70px" height="70px">
    <div class="outer-wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="slide slide1"></div>
            <div class="slide slide2"></div>
            <div class="slide slide3"></div>
            <div class="slide slide4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried using **window.addEventListener('scroll')** but not getting any scrolled value. I tried debugging Js code in chrome but function is not even invoking on scrolling.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    console.log(Scrolled);
});
```

Comment: What do you think about sharing your relevant code with us so we can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `addEventListener` on scroll of `div.outer-wrapper` and get `scrollTop`

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("outer-wrapper")[0].addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    var div = document.getElementsByClassName("outer-wrapper")[0].scrollTop;
    console.log(div);
});
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#log {
    position: fixed;
    width: 500px;
    height: 25px;
    border: solid black 1px;
    z-index: 999;
}

img{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 50%;
    left: 90vw;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
}

.outer-wrapper {
    height: 100vw;
    width: 100vh;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    scrollbar-width: none;  /*---Firefox property---*/
    -ms-overflow-style: none; /*---i.e. family---*/
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;  /*---Chrome and Safari*/
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 400vw;
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
}


.slide {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
.slide1 {
    background-color: teal;
}
.slide2 {
    background-color: tomato;
}
.slide3 {
    background-color: slateblue;
}
.slide4 {
    background-color: palevioletred;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Horizonral scroll</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img draggable="false" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/arrow_right_alt1-512.png" alt="arrow_right" width="70px" height="70px">
    <div class="outer-wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="slide slide1"></div>
            <div class="slide slide2"></div>
            <div class="slide slide3"></div>
            <div class="slide slide4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed.
But how come it did not worked when I set `addEventListener` scroll of `window`?

Comment: @NevKenbecause it is scroll in outer-wrapper where you set overflow-y: scroll; and rotate

Answer (score 0):

You can use `element.scrollTop` and `element.scrollLeft` to get the vertical and horizontal offset, respectively, that has been scrolled. element can be document.body if you care about the whole page. You can compare it to `element.offsetHeight` and `element.offsetWidth` (again, element may be the body) if you need percentages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what you said here didn't helped me at this moment. I am kinda new to this `scroll` stuff.